# Can't access BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

I have an ASUS P8H77-V motherboard, and I can't access the BIOS on startup. My operating system loads just fine, and the motherboard splash screen does appear. But when I press `delete` the BIOS won't load (when the motherboard splash screen appears). This has worked many times in the past, and I didn't install any software recently that would affect this.

I did update my BIOS a few weeks ago, but I could still access them on the splash screen. This has only been happening the last few days.

My keyboard does work when this screen appears, so that isn't the problem. Also, this screen used to say `Press del to access BIOS` and it no longer does so.

Comment: Try `F12` `F10` `F8` or `ESCape` Keys. There must be way to enter the BIOS. Check if BIOS reacts to your keyboard at all if you have USB keyboard. If it doesn't react to USB you do not have USB support enabled in BIOS and you will have to connect PS2 Keyboard.

Comment: I can confirm it should be Delete on this motherboard.

Comment: Try another keyboard. Even better if you have keyboards with different connectors (both USB and PS/2) so you can pinpoint the problem even more.

Comment: I have gotten in to the BIOS with this keyboard before. The keyboard does power on (lights up), and I haven't changed any BIOS settings...

Comment: I also own a keyboard that does power yet doesn't allow me to enter bios. Try a different keyboard, and try pushing all the F buttons repeatedly

Answer (score 6):

Here is possible list of Keys:

> **AMI** (American Megatrends) - AMIBIOS, AMI BIOS
>
> Press Del when after powering on the computer. Some older motherboards
>   that use **AMIBIOS** may prompt for the *F1* or *F2* key instead.
>
> **AwardBIOS**, Award BIOS
>
> Press the Del key to enter the BIOS Setup Utility on nearly all
>   AwardBIOS powered motherboards. Some older systems using Award's BIOS
>   software asked for *Ctrl+Alt+Esc* to enter BIOS.
>
> **DTK BIOS**
>
> Press the Esc key to enter BIOS, right after powering on the PC.
>   Microid Research -
>
> **MR BIOS**
>
> Press *F1* to access the BIOS setup utility.
>
> **Phoenix-Award BIOS**
>
> Press Del during the Power On Self Test, immediately after the
>   computer starts. Many older Phoenix BIOS systems required
>   *Ctrl+Alt+Esc*, *Ctrl+Alt+Ins*, or *Ctrl+Alt+S* to access BIOS. If you're
>   still having troubles entering BIOS or can't figure out what company
>   supplied the BIOS on your motherboard, here are some keyboard commands
>   you might want to randomly try in addition to the any of the ones
>   listed above:
>
> *F3 F4 F10 F12* Tab *Ctrl+Alt+F3* *Ctrl+Alt+Del Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Del* (using
>   *Del* from the keypad) *Ctrl+Insert* *Ctrl+Shift+Esc* *Fn*+[any "F" function
>   key] (on some laptops)

Check if BIOS reacts to your keyboard at all if you have USB keyboard. 
If it doesn't react to USB you do not have USB support enabled in BIOS and you will have to connect PS2 Keyboard

To enable BIOS suppor for USB devices follow this [tutorial](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/bios-beginners,1126-6.html).

Comment: I can confirm it should be Delete on this motherboard, and the default BIOS settings should be fine.  This is probably an issue with the keyboard not initializing quickly enough (it is wireless or needs a lot of power) - try another.